# How to change the font size of the tick labels in contour plot colorbar in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I am using `plot_ly` to plot a contour plot. The code is as follows:

```
X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Y = c(seq(from = 1, to = 17, by = 1))
Z = matrix(runif(17*6), ncol=17)
m <- list(colorbar=list(title = "hi"))
plot_ly(
  x = X, 
  y = Y, 
  z = t(Z), 
  type = "contour",
  opacity = 100,
  fillcolor = "FALSE",
  line = list(width = 1.5),
  contours = list(showlabels = TRUE, 
                  labelfont = list(size = fs, color = 'white')), 
  color = I('black')
) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "X", titlefont = list(size = fs), 
                      ticktext = c("9:00", "9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30"), 
                      tickvals = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                      tickmode = "array", 
                      tickfont = list(size=fs)),
         yaxis = list(title = "Y", titlefont = list(size = fs), 
                      ticktext = c("0", "30", "60", "90", "120", "150", "180", "210", "240", 
                                   "270", "300", "330", "360", "390", "420", "450", "480"), 
                      tickvals = c(1:17), 
                      tickmode = "array",
                      tickfont = list(size=fs)))
```

The output I get is:

[image: contour plot]

How do I change the font size of the colorbar tick labels (encircled in red)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include `colorbar=list(tickfont=list(size=25))` in your chart setup.

I had some problems with your sample code, so this will have to do:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

p <- plot_ly(
  x = c(-9, -6, -5, -3, -1), 
  y = c(0, 1, 4, 5, 7), 
  z = matrix(c(10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20, 5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625, 2.5, 3.125, 5, 8.125, 12.5, 0.625, 1.25, 3.125,
        6.25, 10.625, 0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10), nrow = 5, ncol = 5), 
  type = "contour",
  colorbar=list(tickfont=list(size=25, color='red')),
  contours = list(
    start = 0,
    end = 8,
    size = 2)
)

p
```

Comment: @ash94 Glad to hear that!